# Algorithm for searching a sequence of strings in two models Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two models with a String and I wanted to ask if there is any way in Dart  to find a sequence of strings in two models? And is it possible somehow to make such an algorithm that would guess which specialization the name of the student / students belongs to? Could this be something like a binary search?

My models:

```
List<Spec> specification = <Spec>[
  Spec(stTitle: 'Math student', id: 1),
  Spec(stTitle: 'Biology student', id: 3),
  Spec(stTitle: 'Chemistry student', id: 4),
];

List<Student> stident = <Student>[
  Student(name: 'David', Sid: 1),
  Student(name: 'Adam'),

  Student(name: 'Anna'),
  Student(name: 'James'),
  Student(name: 'Alex'),
  Student(name: 'Peter'),
  Student(name: 'Amanda')
];

class Spec {
  Spec({
    this.stTitle,
    this.id

  });
  final int id;
  final String stTitle;
}

class Student {
  Student({
    this.name,
    this.Sid

  });
  final int Sid;
  final String name;
}
```

The output I want to get if it is possible:

```
Spec['Math student':['James', 'Alex', 'Amanda'], 'Biology student':['Anna', 'Peter'],'Chemistry student':['David'] ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output is not a valid result I guess. Because it is combining `Map` structure with `List<Spec>`. Pardon me if I'm wrong.

> Spec['Math student':['James', 'Alex', 'Amanda'], 'Biology
> student':['Anna', 'Peter'],'Chemistry student':['David'] ];

> This is `List` `Spec[];` and this is map object `'Math
> student':['James', 'Alex', 'Amanda']'

You can get the desired result as a `Map` instead, with `stTitle` as **key** and `name` of the students in `List` as **values**.

The logic will be using the `Map.iterable` with `List.where`

```
final result = Map.fromIterable(specification,
    key: (item) => item.stTitle,
    value: (item) => (student.where((element) => element.sid == item.id)).map((e) => e.name).toList());

print(result);
```

And output is

```
{Math student: [David, Adam, Anna], Biology student: [James, Amanda], Chemistry student: [Alex, Peter]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but Try using Map for this like this:

1. declare:

```
String h="";
List<String> s=[];
List<Map<String,dynamic> myMap=[];
```

then:

```
for(var d in specification){
h=d.setTitle;
stident=[];
for(var e in stident){
///Try giving condition to check the related subject of student
s.add(e.name);
}
myMap.add({
'$h':s
)}
}
```